# Select all where [first letter starts with B]

Tags: mysql

This is a follow up question to my previous one. I want to write a MYSQL statement that echoes every entry that starts with letter B.

Function.php

```
function getCategory() {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT author FROM lyrics WHERE author [starts with letter B]") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
    <p><a href="##"><?= $row['author']; ?></a></p>
    <?php }
```

Category.php?category=b

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php' ?>
<?php getCategory(); ?>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php' ?>
```

Like that I guess. And then one for every letter of the alphabet, and one with misc (numbers etc)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
SELECT author FROM lyrics WHERE author LIKE 'B%';
```

Make sure you have an index on `author`, though!

Comment: Okay thanks, that was easier then expected. One weird problem I'm having though: Your version works great. But as soon as I change it to like: `$first = $_GET['category'];
 $first = $first[0] . "%";
 
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT author FROM lyrics WHERE author LIKE ".$first."") or die(mysql_error());` it doesn't work anymore. Even if I change `$first = "b%";` it doesn't work.

Comment: Its not weird problem its your misunderstanding of things. % doesn't works with =. if you use equal then you have to provide the exact match when you use ="b%" it found the value b% in the DB not started with b. To find starting values you must have to use like.

Comment: The php above is susceptible to SQL injection. Use prepared statements & placeholders, please.

Comment: @AaronBrown user1333327's code is, not mine. Might want to clarify that.

Comment: Yes, ceejayoz.  Didn't mean to imply your code was the issue.

Comment: why is an index necessary? it won't work for me, but i don't have an index, i believe, that selects everything, so...

Comment: @user1333327 pointing out that you must encapsulate LIKE '".$first."'

Comment: how to get multiple words like if i want B% also and A% also??

Comment: @OmkarWaghe Look into the `OR` keyword.

Answer (score 19):

This will work for MYSQL

```
SELECT Name FROM Employees WHERE Name REGEXP '^[B].*$'
```

In this REGEXP stands for regular expression

and

this is for T-SQL

```
SELECT Name FROM Employees WHERE Name LIKE '[B]%'
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
WHERE LEFT (name_field, 1) = 'B';
```

Comment: This will not use the column index and will full-scan the table, at least in MySQL.

Answer (score 11):

SQL Statement:

```
 SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employeeName LIKE 'A%';
```

Result:

```
Number of Records: 4

employeeID  employeeName    employeeName    Address City    PostalCode  Country

1           Alam             Wipro          Delhi   Delhi   11005      India

2           Aditya           Wipro          Delhi   Delhi   11005      India

3           Alok             HCL            Delhi   Delhi   11005      India

4           Ashok            IBM            Delhi   Delhi   11005      India
```

Answer (score 2):

Following your comment posted to ceejayoz's answer, two things are messed up a litte:

1. `$first` is not an array, it's a string. Replace `$first = $first[0] . "%"` by `$first .= "%"`. Just for simplicity. ([PHP string operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php))
2. The string being compared with `LIKE` operator should be quoted. Replace `LIKE ".$first."")` by `LIKE '".$first."'")`. ([MySQL String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
SELECT author FROM lyrics WHERE author LIKE BINARY 'N%' ORDER BY id ASC
```