# mysql search similar to search in default android contacts app

Tags: mysql, search

I need to make a search in database-table. If i enter "a" in search box it should suggest "antony", "Thomas Antony" , "George John Ani".How To write the search query for such a result.

Comment: Should search be based on a column or with table any column?

Comment: search based on name field in a profile-table

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select all where \[first letter starts with B\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156965/select-all-where-first-letter-starts-with-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//answer edited

for the purpose you need to use **REGEXP**,SQLite3 supports the REGEXP operator, check this out

```
SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `name` REGEXP '[[:<:]]A'
```

Hope this will guide you.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple:

Contains a:

```
SELECT *
FROM profile
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', `a` , '%');
```

Starts with a:

```
SELECT *
FROM profile
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT(`a` , '%');
```

Comment: thnkz, but this will show all names with an 'a' in it. I need only names that have a word starting with 'a'.

Comment: @vanooja see my updated answer. The output shown in your question will gain by my first query.