# SELECT all_data WHERE value_in_column LIKE specific_string

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I have a MySQL database with a table that contains a lot of data for a certain vehicle across many different days. In this table there is a column called `time_stamp` that has the date the data was taken like so:

```
ID   UnitID   time_stamp         data   more_data
0    56       2016-08-10 12:01   asdf   12
1    57       2016-08-09 11:19   ghjk   34
2    57       2016-08-09 9:35    qwer   56
3    58       2016-08-09 1:16    tyui   78
```

I want to select everything in the table where `UnitID LIKE 57` and `time_stamp LIKE 2016-08-09%` so that it would return:

```
ID   UnitID   time_stamp         data   more_data
1    57       2016-08-09 11:19   ghjk   34
2    57       2016-08-09 9:35    qwer   56
```

I have tried `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE time_stamp LIKE 2016-08-09% AND UnitID LIKE 57;` but I keep getting a `Error Code: 1054` telling me that there is an `unknown column in 'where clause'`. I am still very new to MySQL but I can usually figure out what I need to do with the help of the [*MySQL Docs*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/), however this one I cannot figure out.  I have also looked for similar questions like [*this one here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156965/select-all-where-first-letter-starts-with-b), but nothing I have found is able to accomplish exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` is for string matching and as such is comparatively slow to compared to more appropriate operators. Your query would be better with a WHERE such as this:

```
WHERE UnitID = 57 AND time_stamp BETWEEN '2016-08-09 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-09 23:59:29'
```

That said, MySQL's main objection to the query you had was probably that you did not enclose `2016-08-09%` in quotes.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I chose this one because it is being implemented into a program and it's easier to implement when the `time` after the specified date doesn't change. And as a side not I did have `2016-08-09%` in quotes but I used " ` " as quotes and that messes with Stack Overflow input formatting.

Comment: Ah, yeah `\`` would've made MySQL expect you to have a field **named** `2016-08-09%`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `LIKE` clauses here. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE
time_stamp >= Convert(datetime,'2016-08-09')
AND
time_stamp < Convert(datetime,'2016-08-10')
AND
UnitID = 57
```

Comment: This answer also works but due to the date formatting it would be harder to implement as the user only inputs the first date, in this case `2016-08-09` and the program would have to increment for the second date by `+1`. This would cause and issue with something like `2016-08-31` because there is no `2016-08-32`. Of course I could set limits and work around it but other answers were easier to implement. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to need `LIKE` for this query because the data that you're looking for isn't `TEXT`, `VARCHAR`, or `CHAR` data. Try doing this in your predicate:

```
WHERE UnitID = 57 AND DATE(time_stamp) = '2016-08-09'
```

Comment: For some reason I could not get this syntax to work and I imagine it is because of the formatting of `time_stamp` being a data & time *not* just a date. I got what I needed from others answers but either way thank you for the response!